How analyze router syslog
Router has https, VPN, PostgreSql and VNC ports open. I want to know user names and passwords used in attacks by countries and ip addresses.
Currently free kiwi syslog server from solarwinds.com in Windows is used to collect Asus RT-AC87U router syslog.
AsusWrt-Merlin firmware is running in router, can changed to DD-WRT or other if this helps.
Kiwi shows syslog entries as plain text, not formatted to columns:

Enties cannot filtered or sorted by ip address, id addresses are not resolved to countries, no port scanning, tried user names and passwords are available.
Where to find free tool to analyze router syslog for intrusion attacks? Maybe some Asus Merlin or DD-WRT plugin or other has such features?
How syslog can split info columns for easier viewing?

There are dozens upon dozens of programs like Solarwinds, you just have to configure the parsing of the system logs yourself, specific recommendation on a specific tool would be out of scope. You would have to configure the router to log to a syslog which has the software to parse the system logs. I have no idea if that router can be made to do that.

The format you're looking at, specifically, is the iptables log format. It's not part of syslog proper; syslog only considers it a plain text message. so while some syslog collectors might have the features to parse it, I would probably search for an iptables log analyzer that's completely separate from the syslog collector. (I don't know of any. So far I've managed with grep and Perl.)
